# How to conditionally show Rxweb Reactive pattern validator for Angular application?

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I have been creating an angular application which uses Rxweb validation framework. It works really well with most predefined validations. However, there are cases where I need to look for duplicates which reside on the server.

I have posted the link an example on stackblitz [Validator.pattern not updating](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnu5nx)

The documentation for RxWeb says that you can put a conditionalExpression in the validator so that if the condition is NOT met the validator will not be used.

Example:

```
noneof: any[] = ["toast"];

ngOnInit() {
this.group = this.formBuilder.group({

  name: [this.course.name, [RxwebValidators.required({
    conditionalExpression: (x) => {
      var result = this.noneof.indexOf("toast") < 0;
      return result;
    },
  })]]
 });
}
```

As you can see on the example page the required is off because the condition is not met(ie. 'toast' is in the array).

The next condition example the condition is met and validation is on as expected.

```
noneof: any[] = ["toast"];

ngOnInit() {
this.group = this.formBuilder.group({
  title: [this.course.title, [RxwebValidators.required({
    conditionalExpression: (x) => {
      var result = this.noneof.indexOf("toast") > -1;
      return result;
    },
  })]],
});
}
```

Now, if you play around in this field you will soon realize that as soon as the text is empty it shows the validation message until a character is placed in it.

In the third example I have regex pattern with a condition. The condition is not met because the word "toas" doestn't match the required "toast". Now if I type 't' at the end the validator doesn't become live as expected even though the condition is met.

```
noneof: any[] = ["toast"];

ngOnInit() {
this.group = this.formBuilder.group({

  category: [this.course.category, [RxwebValidators.pattern(
    {
      expression: { 'duplicateTitle': /_NONONONO_/ },
      conditionalExpression: (x) => {
        var result = this.noneof.indexOf(x.category) > -1;
        return result;
      },
    })]],
  });
}
```

The regular expression is just meant to fail to show the error. I have used this because I haven't found any other way to implement logic to check for a value in the list. The list is intended to hold a list of duplicate categories that cannot be used. If at any time the text in the text box matches an item in the list. The condition should be met and the pattern should fail. Note, the x.category is a reference to the item that is being updated. Even though the condition is met as expected it doesn't show the validation message. The very next text change updates and shows the validation message.

You can [play around](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnu5nx) by typing 'toast' then type 's' and the validation message shows.

complete.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see someone who can comment on this problem and give me a better solution but it is easy to force the update by calling the updateValueAndValidity on ngModelChange.

```
<input type="text" formControlName="title" class="form-control" 
   (ngModelChange)="group.controls.title.updateValueAndValidity()" />
```

You can look at the [working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnu5nx-bpegzw) where the change updates immediately.